# Dynamic Cursor SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have this global cursor that is created by a string like this, however when execute, I get this error message :

> A cursor with the name 'crsDTO' does not exist.

Code:

```
DECLARE @Cursor NVARCHAR(MAX); 

SET @Cursor = 'DECLARE crsDTO CURSOR FOR SELECT p.ID, p.Price, p.Count FROM Business.Products'; 

exec sp_executesql @Cursor; 

OPEN crsDTO; -- fails here <<<<<<<<

BEGIN TRY
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsDTO INTO @ID, @Price, @Count;

    WHILE 0 = @@fetch_status
    BEGIN
        PRINT(@ID)

        FETCH NEXT FROM crsDTO INTO @ID, @Price, @Count;
    END;

    CLOSE crsDTO;
    DEALLOCATE crsDTO;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    CLOSE crsDTO;
    DEALLOCATE crsDTO;
END CATCH
```

I looked around everything looks to be fine.. and I can't find why it's not working.

**UPDATE**

This SP is going to bulk update either price or stock or both. i might be wrong and there might be alternative way which is much better than this i am open to all correction.
However this cursor is going to be filtered based on user opinion. it can change stock/prices(as percentage amount or basic amount) based on the filters.
so for example user wants bulk change the prices for only specific brandId or combination of BrandId/CategoryId and SupplierId or none of them(which means every product).

```
CREATE procedure [Business].[Product_BulkUpdate]
(   
    @PO_Error             int OUTPUT,
    @PO_ErrorMessage      Nvarchar(Max) OUTPUT,
    @PO_Step              int OUTPUT,
    @CallerUserId         uniqueidentifier,
    @CategoryId           uniqueidentifier = null,
    @BrandId              uniqueidentifier = null,
    @SupplierId           uniqueidentifier = null,
    @ProductName          nvarchar(max) = null,
    @Amount               float = null,
    @AmountPercentage     float = null,
    @IsInStock            bit = null
)
as


DECLARE @ID Uniqueidentifier;
DECLARE @Price int;
DECLARE @Count int;
DECLARE @KW nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @Cursor nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @WhereClause nvarchar(max);

    set @WhereClause = ' 1=1 ';
    if (@ProductName is not null)
        set @WhereClause =@WhereClause + ' And p.Name like N'''+'%'+cast(@ProductName as nvarchar(4000))+'%'+''' ';
    if (@CategoryId is not null)
        set @WhereClause =@WhereClause + ' And c.ID in (SELECT cf.id FROM Business.GetCategoryChilds('''+CAST(@CategoryId as nvarchar(50)) +''') cf) ';
    if(@SupplierId is not null)
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND p.SupplierId in (' + CAST(@SupplierId as nvarchar(50)) + ') ';
    IF(@BrandId is not null)
        set @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND bb.ID in (' + CAST(@BrandId as nvarchar(50)) + ')'; 

    SET @Cursor = ' DECLARE crsDTO cursor for
        SELECT p.ID, p.Price, p.Count FROM Business.Products p
        INNER JOIN Kernel.BaseEntity b on b.ID = p.ID AND b.IsDelete = 0
        LEFT JOIN Business.Brand bb on bb.ID = p.BrandId
        LEFT JOIN Business.Category c on c.ID = p.CategoryId
        LEFT JOIN MarketPlace.Supplier s on s.SupplierId = p.SupplierId

        WHERE '+@WhereClause+' AND c.CategoryTypeId = 10700';   

begin 
    --- Auto generated procedure
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @PO_Error = 0;
    SET @PO_Step = 0;
    SET @PO_ErrorMessage = '';
    BEGIN TRY  
            exec sp_executesql @Cursor;
            SET @PO_Step = 1;
            OPEN crsDTO;
            BEGIN TRY
                FETCH NEXT FROM crsDTO INTO @ID, @Price, @Count;
                while 0 = @@fetch_status
                BEGIN
                    IF(@IsInStock = 0) BEGIN
                        IF(@Amount is not null and @AmountPercentage is null) BEGIN
                            IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Business.Products WHERE ID = @ID) BEGIN
                                UPDATE Business.Products SET                            
                                    Price = @Price + @Amount
                                WHERE ID = @ID                  
                            END
                        END else IF(@AmountPercentage is not null and @Amount is null) BEGIN
                            IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Business.Products WHERE ID = @ID) BEGIN
                                UPDATE Business.Products SET                            
                                    Price = (@Price * (@AmountPercentage / 100))
                                WHERE ID = @ID              
                            END
                        END
                    END ELSE IF(@IsInStock = 1) BEGIN
                        IF(@Amount is not null and @AmountPercentage is null) BEGIN
                            IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Business.Products WHERE ID = @ID) BEGIN
                                UPDATE Business.Products SET                            
                                    Price = @Price + @Amount,
                                    Count = 0
                                WHERE ID = @ID                  
                            END
                        END else IF(@AmountPercentage is not null and @Amount is null) BEGIN
                            IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Business.Products WHERE ID = @ID) BEGIN
                                UPDATE Business.Products SET                            
                                    Price = (@Price * (@AmountPercentage / 100)),
                                    Count = 0
                                WHERE ID = @ID              
                            END
                        END ELSE IF(@Amount is null and @AmountPercentage is null) BEGIN
                            IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Business.Products WHERE ID = @ID) BEGIN
                                UPDATE Business.Products SET
                                    Count = 0
                                WHERE ID = @ID
                            END
                        END
                    END
                    SET @PO_Step = 2;
                FETCH NEXT FROM crsDTO INTO @ID, @Price, @Count;
                END;
                CLOSE crsDTO;
                DEALLOCATE crsDTO;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                CLOSE crsDTO;
                DEALLOCATE crsDTO;
                SET @PO_Error = ERROR_NUMBER();
                SET @PO_ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
            END CATCH   
        END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @PO_Error = ERROR_NUMBER();
        SET @PO_ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    END CATCH
END;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=60e9befd6f57f8b3d00f0cc5f8a41d4d

Comment: why did you do such things?

Comment: A dynamic cursor implies a real design flaw here. What are you actually trying to achieve here? Perhaps if you explain that we can change you onto a better solution that doesn't need such a thing.

Comment: Missing table alias `p`: `SELECT p.ID, p.Price, p.Count FROM Business.Products';`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda nope i edited that just to be more clear and i missed the `p`. no worries its not alias.

Comment: I posted working demo, I cannot reproduce your case. Please elaborate how you run it

Comment: @LukaszSzozda i checked your example on fiddle and ran it with my own data but it doesnt work. let me post the real SP

Comment: @Valkyrie That's the point, because we see the simplified working scenario. My guess is that you are dealocating cursor prematurely or it is in different scope

Comment: Shouldn't you add BEGIN END to wrap SP, after AS and at the last END

Comment: @LukaszSzozda sure I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192472/discussion-between-valkyrie-and-lukasz-szozda).

Comment: OK I know where is the error

Comment: Careful, things like `' And p.Name like N'''+'%'+cast(@ProductName as nvarchar(4000))+'%'+''' '` are an injection nightmare. You should be parametrising your SQL, not injecting the values. Also, if `@ProductName` has a `'` in it, your code will fail.

Comment: @Larnu yeah i changed it all no need to do cursor even. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add check if cursor exists:

```
-- ....
BEGIN CATCH
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','crsDTO')>=-1
    BEGIN
        CLOSE crsDTO;
        DEALLOCATE crsDTO;
    END   
END CATCH
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=83a215e8d3b518d513a77746fee4a803)**

Using global cursor/row-by-row approach does not seems to be the best solution.